# How to install ROS Noetic on ubuntu 20.04 without adding the repository http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal InRelease

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, repository, ros

How can I download the `.deb` packages for the ROS Noetic and then install in Ubuntu 20.04, because the system server has very limited access to repositories that's why I am trying to figure out this way. Can anyone please share the detail so that I can do it because I am new for Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following steps which discussed on the link to solve this problem
https://askubuntu.com/a/84323/1614164